# Mocking LocalDateTime with PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm trying to mock a class using `LocalDateTime` objects in a method. Mocking the class causes a:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException Reason: [source error]
>   toInstant(java.time.ZoneOffset) not found in java.time.LocalDateTime

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36908084/powermock-does-not-create-mock-for-java-time-zoneddatetime) related question (the class is final) - and tried to do so in the test setUp:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(LocalDateTime.class);
```

But I still get the same error. A non-working test set-up is:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(LocalDateTime.class);
    LocalDateTime ld = LocalDateTime.now();
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    now.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    PowerMockito.when(LocalDateTime.toInstant(any(ZoneOffset.class))).thenReturn(now); // <= fails with above exception
}
```

How can I mock correctly the `LocalDateTime` class so that Mockito can call the method `toInstant`?

Comment: I agree with both points in the answer you linked: You need to @PrepareForTest the class that interacts with `LocalDateTime`, and ideally you should refactor your code so you don't need to mock those classes—particularly because Java Time so nicely lets you create Clock instances for testing. Closing as dupe; at the very least please edit in your @PrepareForTest to indicate why that answer doesn't suffice.

Answer (score 0):

To mock classes from JDK you need to prepare those classes for testing by using `@PrepareForTest(LocalDateTime.class)` (and of course your test runner should be `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`.

But a better way would be to avoid `PowerMockito` and design your classes in such a way that you can inject `LocalDateTime` into it.

PowerMockito is a powerful tool that should be used very rarely, as a last resort only when you have to do some tricky code coverage and your manager is pointing a gun at your head. It's the easy and quick way out, not a good one.

Comment: Thank for your answers guys ! I finally solved it by mocking an upper class. So PowerMockito wouldn't even try to mock my class with the **LocalDateTime**.